# How do I install the pubs or northwind databases for sql server 2008?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I'm trying to locate the download for the pubs or northwind databases for sql server 2008, rather than the new Adventureworks database that is recommended.

Where do I go to find the download for these databases?

Answer (score 4):

http://msftdbprodsamples.codeplex.com/